# Is Realm Encrypted By Default on iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, realm

I haven't been able to determine whether Realm is encrypted by default on iOS.
Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Realm Documentation section about **[Using Realm with Background App Refresh](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-realm-with-background-app-refresh)**:

> On iOS 8 and above, files inside apps are automatically encrypted using [NSFileProtection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Protection_Values) whenever the device is locked. If your app attempts to do any work involving Realm while the device is locked and the `NSFileProtection` attributes of your Realm files are set to encrypt them **(which is the case by default)**, an `open() failed: Operation not permitted` exception will be thrown.

Beyond that Realm brings its own native file [Encryption](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#encryption) support.

> Realm supports encrypting the database file on disk with AES-256+SHA2 by supplying a 64-byte encryption key when creating a Realm.
>
> ```
> // Generate a random encryption key
> let key = NSMutableData(length: 64)!
> SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, key.length,
>     UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(key.mutableBytes))
>
> // Open the encrypted Realm file
> let config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: key)
> do {
>   let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
>   // Use the Realm as normal
>   let dogs = realm.objects(Dog).filter("name contains 'Fido'")
> } catch let error as NSError {
>   // If the encryption key is wrong, `error` will say that it's an invalid database
>   fatalError("Error opening realm: \(error)")
> }
> ```
>
> This makes it so that all of the data stored on disk is transparently encrypted and decrypted with AES-256 as needed, and verified with a SHA-2 HMAC. The same encryption key must be supplied every time you obtain a Realm instance.

Comment: @WilliamGrand this URL (and all other under `tech-notes`) results in 404.

Comment: Thanks @interDist. The link changed just a couple of days after I posted it. I just deleted the comment. 

Here is a link with the updated syntax: https://docs.realm.io/platform/self-hosted/manage/security/security-recommendations

Answer (score -1):

If you use your own key, provide custom data:

```
func setup(with encryptionKey: String) {
    Swift.assert(encryptionKey.count == 64, "Base 64 encoded encryptionKey unavailable")
    let data = Data(base64Encoded: encryptionKey)
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: data)
}

let key = "asdasnkdjbaskdjbfadshvjadskvkdsvcjavsdjhvcjdhjsakhdkjsahdkasdasd"
setup(with: key)
```